# Get a URI path to APK from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How can I get path to APK file in Intent when I attached my activity to "Open with.." list?

Code of manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".InstallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_install"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code of activity (InstallActivity.java)

```
public class InstallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_install);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Uri` to the APK via `getIntent().getData()`.

If that `Uri` happens to have a `file` scheme, you can call `getPath()` on the `Uri` to get the path.

More likely, the `Uri` will have a `content` scheme, in which case you cannot get the path, as there does not have to be a file, let alone one that you can access via the filesystem. You will need to [consume the content identified by the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) using other APIs, such as `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

It is conceivable, though unlikely, that the `Uri` will have another scheme, such as `android.resource` or `http`. `android.resource` will be handled by `openInputStream()`. `http` would require an HTTP client API, as would `https`. And so on for any other schemes.

Ideally, you augment your `<intent-filter>` to add `<data>` elements to constrain your app to the schemes that you support.